# ERROR: Build failed: wait: remote command exited without exit status or exit signal

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to setup Gitlab CI Runner and got stuck due to following Error.

[error in Gitlab CI runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REkhm.png)

Find below the details and error. Above snapshot shows the Gitlab error and the same was found in Linux Terminal which is in the link given below.

http://pastebin.com/raw/rWTbjuNC

I am not being able to find out what exactly the error is after looking into logs from runner in debug mode.

Comment: I was following article ---> http://www.greysonparrelli.com/setting-up-android-builds-in-gitlab-ci/